# Is there a pun in "as absolutely inhuman as bees"?

Tags: word-meaning

The whole paragraph goes like

> The lower animals do not have this splendid freedom. They are limited most of them, to absolute infallibility. Cats, for all their good side, never make mistakes. I have never seen a maladroit, clumsy, or blundering cat. Dogs are sometimes fallible, occasionally able to make charming minor mistakes, but they get this way by trying to mimic their masters. Fish are flawless in everything they do. Individual cells in a tissue are mindless machines, perfect in their performance, **as absolutely inhuman as bees**.
>
> *--- http://www.lagcc.cuny.edu/cpe/sample1b.html*

Can anyone please tell me if there is a pun in the last sentence for me?

Comment: ...Maybe I don't see it, but I'm fairly sure there is none.

Comment: @SF. Nor can I. This is a question in the Post-graduate Entrance Exam, and the answer only tells where the pun locates (the bold sentence), but not how it can be a pun.

Comment: I suppose it *could* be argued that *bees* also represents an ungrammatical 3sg of *be*, for "as absolutely inhuman as is" -which would be an instance of "human fallibility". But that's very far-fetched, and I don't believe it for a minute.

Comment: Another - equally far fetched, but at least containing a bit of (rude) humor - would be reading "as bees" as "Aspies", a moniker for people suffering Asperger's Syndrome (which might be seen as 'damaging their humanity'). Calling aspies "inhuman" (and comparing them to fish) would be definitely overstepping the level of political correctness usually accepted in Entrance Exams though.

Comment: It may be a misunderstanding or mistranslation. To me it looks as though the text is drawing atention to the idea that, though the living cells in a human body make up a human being, individually they are no more human than bees individually are the hive. I think they may have intended the word "paradox" rather than "pun".

Comment: Could it be elsewhere in the last sentence? You refer to "the bold sentence", but only the last five words of the last sentence are emphasized in your quotation. Which is it? Where do you see this question?

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung A question set up by a Chinese teacher I'm afraid. Maybe I shall consider it in a Chinglish way? In the question, it mentioned that there was a pun in the bold part, not the whole sentence. Please help to edit this question. I don't know how to express it...

Comment: @SF. Besides, "Aspies" is too much beyond our knowledge...

Answer (score 1):

No, there appears to be no pun.  As [Jonathan Garber suggests](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13691/is-there-a-pun-in-as-absolutely-inhuman-as-bees#comment24042_13691), it may be a misunderstanding of the word *pun*.  Failing that, I think it's simply in error.

I don't consider the other possible "puns" brought up in the comments credible enough to mention here, although the comments do have a useful purpose: that everyone had to stretch so far to interpret the sentence as containing a pun tells us that it does not, in fact, contain one.